# Window Vista Taskbar Always Freezes

Tags: windows-vista, freeze, taskbar

I have a Windows Vista (yeah, I know ugh) laptop. After start up the taskbar always freezes. The work around is go to Start Task Manager, Processes tab, select "explorer.exe," and click End Process. While still in the Start Task Manager, select File > New Task (Run...) and then type "explore.exe" (without quotes) to get my taskbar to work.

Is there anyway to permanently solve the problem of the frozen task bar without having to use this work around every time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you will need to address is to find out if that there are processes running with start up that are causing it to slow down and crash.

Press Start
Type "msconfig" no quotes needed
then click startup
disabling anything you do not need during start up should help.

things you might should disable could include, adobe launches for acrobat reader, google update software, java updaters etc.
If you are worried about disabling the item then you should google it to be sure. I hope this help.